# IndexError when plotting subplots in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

(Using ipython notebook..)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Average': {'April- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'August- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'December- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'February- 2015': 94.400000000000006,
  'January- 2015': 94.400000000000006,
  'July- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'June- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'May- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'November- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'October- 2014': 94.400000000000006,
  'September- 2014': 94.400000000000006},
 'Number': {'April- 2014': 80,
  'August- 2014': 86,
  'December- 2014': 110,
  'February- 2015': 11,
  'January- 2015': 104,
  'July- 2014': 90,
  'June- 2014': 83,
  'May- 2014': 108,
  'November- 2014': 118,
  'October- 2014': 127,
  'September- 2014': 107}})
```

Per the documentation listed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#subplots) you should be able to do this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(15, 8))
df['Number'].plot(ax=axes[0, 0])
```

However, it results in: `IndexError: too many indices for array`

What's the easiest way to plot subplots?

Comment: Check your `axes.shape`. It's `(2,)` so you only need `.plot(ax=axes[0])`. There's also the `subplots=True` argument to DataFrame.plot

Comment: Ah, interesting. Not very intuitive. That solved it though. Thanks!

Comment: @TomAugspurger You should post it as an answer so this post doesn't remain unanswered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will copy Tom's answer from the comments here.

> Check your `axes.shape`. It's `(2,)` so you only need `.plot(ax=axes[0])`.
>   There's also the `subplots=True` argument to `DataFrame.plot`

It should work.